# How to print arrays?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm having trouble with this step for my assignment. Here is the assignment:

> Add code to load the combo box with the first element in each row of the rectangular array, and display the first item in the combo box when the form is loaded.

This is the given array:

```
 string[,] conversionTable = {
        { "Miles to kilometers", "Miles", "Kilometers", "1.6093" },
        { "Kilometers to miles", "Kilometers", "Miles", "0.6214" },
        { "Feet to meters", "Feet", "Meters", "0.3048" },
        { "Meters to feet", "Meters", "Feet", "3.2808" },
        { "Inches to centimeters", "Inches", "Centimeters", "2.54" },
        { "Centimeters to inches", "Centimeters", "Inches", "0.3937" }
```

I'm using this picture to help me:

[image: SOQ60199177]

If I use this image then would the numbers across be 0, 1, 2, 3 and the numbers on  the side be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5? Since you start counting at 0 and the array size is 4X6?

Comment: Do you know how to put a breakpoint for debugging?
Put a breakpoint after this array is initialized, and it will show you elements.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, I'm not sure how to put one I thought it was close to the line numbers on the side but I don't see the red dot for it

Comment: RIght click in the line you want to add a breakpoint to (the line must contain code), in the menu click on Breakpoint -> Insert Breakpoint.

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag is only intended for questions about the Visual Studio application. Your question sounds like you want to display this array in a WinForms UI.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019 This would help, and I assume easy to google question shall not be easy to google answer?

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible to iterate over any 2-dimensional arrays using nested for loops. Think of this as a table with rows and columns, where the first for loop selects the row and the second for loop selects the column.

When you've selected the column, simply perform the function you wish, in this case `Console.WriteLine(column[j])`, where `column[j]` is the column you want to print to the console or wherever you might want to output the result.

```
string[,] conversionTable = {
        { "Miles to kilometers", "Miles", "Kilometers", "1.6093" },
        { "Kilometers to miles", "Kilometers", "Miles", "0.6214" },
        { "Feet to meters", "Feet", "Meters", "0.3048" },
        { "Meters to feet", "Meters", "Feet", "3.2808" },
        { "Inches to centimeters", "Inches", "Centimeters", "2.54" },
        { "Centimeters to inches", "Centimeters", "Inches", "0.3937" }
    };

for(int i = 0; i < conversionTable.Length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < conversionTable.Length; j++){
        Console.WriteLine(conversionTable[i][j]);
    }
}
```

You'd probably want to use a class with properties and rather use a `List<ConversionTable>` but that's not the assignment I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like an array of arrays. That might help. If you do that, you see that `conversionTable` has six elements, which are themselves arrays. The first subscript will choose which "sub-array". The second subscript will then choose the element in that "sub-array".

Comment: you mean jagged array. But this is not a syntax for JA initialization

Comment: @T.S. The concept is  the same for any multidimensional array. It's also a valuable mental picture when dealing with Lists of Lists and the like.

Comment: I don't think so. I picture a multi-dimentional array as ...(for example 2D array) as a table with constant rows and fields. Jugged array on the other hand will have arbitrary number of dimensions where you can have other arrays with arbitrary number of items

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to do something like this:

```
    private static void TestArray()
    {
        string[,] conversionTable = {
            { "Miles to kilometers", "Miles", "Kilometers", "1.6093" },
            { "Kilometers to miles", "Kilometers", "Miles", "0.6214" },
            { "Feet to meters", "Feet", "Meters", "0.3048" },
            { "Meters to feet", "Meters", "Feet", "3.2808" },
            { "Inches to centimeters", "Inches", "Centimeters", "2.54" },
            { "Centimeters to inches", "Centimeters", "Inches", "0.3937" }
        };

        //This loop for filling ComboBox
        for(int i = 0; i < conversionTable.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            var v = conversionTable[i,0];
            Console.WriteLine(v); //Fill ComboBox
        }

        var selectedIndex = 2; //"Feet to meters"

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        //This loop for displaying values for the selected 
        //... conversion method from the ComboBox
        for(int i = 1; i < conversionTable.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(conversionTable[selectedIndex,i]);
        }
    }
```

I have combined both steps in one method for brevity. The first `for` loop would be used to fill the `ComboBox` using `Add` instead of `Console.WriteLine`. The variable `selectedIndex` represents the index of the item selected in the `ComboBox`. Use that value to grab the `Array` of strings you want to display elsewhere. Notice that the second `for` loop starts at index 1 instead of 0, since I assume you don't need to display the same value you just selected from the `ComboBox`.

Comment: I don't get offended when I am downvoted. I know it is a part of the 'risk' of answering questions. But, since we are all here to learn it would be really nice if the person who downvoted would at least explained the reason for doing so. Thank you.